# Can I calculate the reciprocal of a harmonic series in wolfram mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving

hello this way is how you solve an harmonic series in mathematical.
with the first 10 values

```
Sum[1/n,{n,1,10}] # solution is 2.49
```

i want know how to do it this if i want reach up a number like 5

how many values i need for get 5 as a result. do you understand me?

Comment: Have you already seen `HarmonicNumber[]`?

Comment: The least k such that HarmonicNumber[k]>=n forms Sloane's [A004080](https://oeis.org/A004080): {0,1,4,11,31,83,...}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The partial sum for `m` terms is

```
h[m_] = Sum[1/n, {n, 1, m}]

(* HarmonicNumber[m] *)

Solve[{h[m] == 5, m > 0}, m] // N

(* Solve::fexp: Warning: Solve used FunctionExpand to transform 
   the system. Since FunctionExpand transformation rules are only 
   generically correct, the solution set might have been altered. *)

(* {{m -> 82.8275}} *)
```

So it will take at least `83` terms.

```
h /@ {82, 83} // N

(* {4.99002, 5.00207} *)
```

**EDIT:** Or,

```
Ceiling[InverseFunction[h][5.]]

(* 83 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have more complicated summands, let NMinimize doe the job (with a little help).

```
g[m_?NumericQ] := Sum[Sqrt[n]/(n - 1)^1.1, {n, 2, m}]

NMinimize[{m, g[m] >= 10 && 10 < m < 100 && m \[Element] Integers}, m,
   MaxIterations -> 1000]

(*   {42., {m -> 42}}   *)

{g[41], g[42]}

(*   {9.96992, 10.079}   *)
```